# R: ggvis : how do I rotate X axis by 90 degrees?

Tags: r, ggvis

ggvis brings interactivity over ggplot and this is great adoption driver. 
In ggplot, I often rotate axis by adding

```
 + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

what is the same for ggvis?

consider

```
mtcars %>%
  ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg) %>%
  layer_points()
```

EDIT: Also, the labels must be exactly opposite the ticker mark to make the graph perfectly readable.

Comment: You might read through the ggvis "Axes and Legends" document [here](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/axes-legends.html) or look at the help page examples for `add_axis`.

Answer (score 3):

There is an additional parameter "baseline" to manage the position of legend in relation to a ticker mark.

```
mtcars %>%
    ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg) %>%
    layer_points() %>% 
    add_axis("x", properties = axis_props(labels = list(angle = 90, 
             align = "left", baseline = "middle")))
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is

```
%>% add_axis("x", properties = axis_props(labels = list(angle = 90, align = "left")))


mtcars %>%
  ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg) %>%
  layer_points() %>% 
  add_axis("x", properties = axis_props(labels = list(angle = 90, align = "left")))
```

[image]

EDIT: there is a problem with moving the label to align with the tick mark. Any comments solving that would be appreciated
[image]